# trigger introJs With a button or link

Tags: bootstrap-tour

I've used this Tutorial in order to create a guide
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/introjs-step-by-step-guide-tutorial/

```
$(function(){
  var introguide = introJs();
  // var startbtn   = $('#startdemotour');
}

introguide.setOptions({
    steps: [
        {
          element: '.nav-bar',
          intro: 'This guided tour will explain the Hongkiat demo page interface.<br><br>Use the arrow keys for navigation or hit ESC to exit the tour immediately.',
          position: 'bottom'
        },
        {
          element: '.nav-logo',
          intro: 'Click this main logo to view a list of all Hongkiat demos.',
          position: 'bottom'
        },
        {
          element: '.nav-title',
          intro: 'Hover over each title to display a longer description.',
          position: 'bottom'
        },
        {
          element: '.readtutorial a',
          intro: 'Click this orange button to view the tutorial article in a new tab.',
          position: 'right'
        },
        {
          element: '.nav-menu',
          intro: "Each demo will link to the previous & next entries.",
          position: 'bottom'
        }
    ]
});
```

But I could not find a way or I did not understand :)
How to trigger introJs With a button or link.
In addition, I've search on the Internet User's Guide
But I did not find enough information on the subject:(

I tried this:

```
<a href = "javascript: void (0);" onclick = "javascript: introJs (). start ();"> Show me how </a>
```

&

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="startIntro();">Show me how</a>
```

But nothing happens

please help me

Comment: Your tutorial page explains this exactly, with examples. ctrl-F "The only line of code we need is to call `introguide.start()`. "

Comment: I do not want the guide load when refreshing the page

Comment: Read the next sentence: "This may be kept inside an event handler which triggers only after the user clicks on a link or button".  There's a code example right after that.

Comment: Can you give me an example
I mean how to use the code
Because I could not figure out <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript: introguide.start();">Show me how</a>   Does not work!

Answer (score 0):

The example is right there on your tutorial page:

```
var startbtn   = $('#startdemotour'); // <-- you need to uncomment this line, or just use $('#startdemotour').on()
startbtn.on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  introguide.start();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Ok,
I was able to run the code
Just use the code that is shown here: view-source:http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/example/programmatic/index.html   work perfect
Guide site code is not clear to me
But it's because I M NOOB